# Overriding sendResetLinkEmail returns nothing

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to send a password reset link via AJAX. I've overridden the `sendResetLinkEmail` method inside my `ForgotPasswordController` to the following:

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail()
{
    $this->validate(request(), ['email' => 'required|email|exists:users']);

    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        request()->only('email')
    );

    echo 'test';
}
```

The validation works perfectly and I do get a responseJSON back if there are errors e.g. invalid email, non-existent email. My problem is that I am not getting any type of response back when there are no validation errors. Not `test`, not anything at all.

When I remove the following I **do** get a response of `test` back:

```
$response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
    request()->only('email')
);
```

It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this may be its help for you!!!

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that it was failing to connect to the SMTP server so it was hanging.

Here is the working code:

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail()
{
    $this->validateEmail(request());

    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        request()->only('email')
    );

    if ($response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
        return response()->json([
            'alert' => true,
            'alert_message' => 'Password reset link emailed!',
        ]);
    }
    else {
        return response()->json(['email' => trans($response)], 422);
    }
}
```

I use `data.hasOwnProperty('alert')` in my jQuery code to determine if an alert should be shown upon `success` AJAX response.